# Conventions of code format in question

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

Just a matter of curiosity. I [posted a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46670798/how-to-convert-bool-to-string-in-a-c-sharp-model-instead-of-the-controller) two days ago someone made edits. Here's a subsample, where a sentence was changed from this:

> Typically, if I have a bool field in my model, it is because the
>   underlying database has a bit value. My users, however, would prefer
>   to have yes/no instead of true/false or checkbox in views. Typically,
>   I convert bool to string in my view model.

to this:

> Typically, if I have a `bool` field in my model, it is because the
>   underlying database has a bit value. My users, however, would prefer
>   to have yes/no instead of true/false or checkbox in views. Typically,
>   I convert `bool` to string in my `ViewModel`.

I'm curious. Why edit my text to mark `bool` and `ViewModel` using code notation and not `bit`, `string`, all other instances of data types in my question? If there was a purpose and underlying method to it, I'd make sure to follow it. The only pattern I could see was that the C# data types were `put in code format`.

It is to help SO database searches? Just curious if there's a reason.

Comment: No real reason. People just seem to *love* using inline code formatting. Over 50% of the time, it's a mistake. It just makes the post harder to read and less semantically meaningful.

Comment: I saw a lot of edits precisely doing that. I thought it was an actual community convention, and I started doing so myself. It seemed appropriate to me when the actual keywords of the language were used (`bool`vs 'a boolean'). Glad the question is raised. And I'm starting to regret [my last edit on a question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17619164)... which was basically just inline code formatting ... :( (along with retagging for burnination)

Comment: In some fairness it wasn't "view model" to `ViewModel` it was "viewmodel" to `ViewModel`. Having said that, it doesn't really make sense that any of it was done. I'd only tend to do this to highlight something in the text to lookout for in the main code block, if that make sense? Also I don't see what value adding the entity-framework tag adds

Comment: @AshleyMedway -- Exactly. I thought you added a tag only if it was directly relevant to that tag, for example, if I was asking about tweaking an EF context.

Comment: While it is conventional to put types in code-quotes, I agree that the edit in question is haphazard and inconsistent. And if you're talking about database types, code-quoting seems less applicable (i.e. even `bool` and `string` are questionable edits), since we're not talking about type identifiers in some specific programming language. I see no need to change the spelling of and quote _"view model"_, and likewise _"bit value"_ (since the data type isn't actually named `bit` per se). I think you'll find a lot of such edits are just people looking for _any_ change to justify an edit for rep.

Comment: _"looking for any change to justify an edit for rep"_ -- though, in this case the editor isn't getting in rep, so maybe it's just a bad habit from when they were, or maybe they're just random. Frankly, I think you'd be justified in reviewing the edit and undoing any changes you didn't agree with (some of the changes seemed useful to me, so I wouldn't recommend a full rollback).

Comment: @PeterDuniho -- That's probably the cause of a lot of needless and perhaps poorly-made edits. Folks trying to mine points and medals in a game where the points really don't matter.

Comment: I guess there's more to it, really. At some point in your career you can just move in and edit posts, without a review process. At that point it is easy to employ your *personal* conventions onto everyone, because having a convention is better than not having one, even if it contradicts everyone else's. I would find it helpful to have a set of conventions, that everyone is following. That would both establish consistency, and take a lot of guesswork and personal preference out of reviewing proposed edits.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yeah, I find that edit rather bizarre. Why did it format both occurrences of `bool` as inline code, but not `bit` or `string`? Why is it changing the English phrase "view model" to a `ViewModel` class, as if the editor was working under the assumption that your view model's base class is `ViewModel`? (This seems to be **really** common in MVVM questions for some reason.)

Perhaps the editor simply missed them. They made a few other changes as well, including removing context that could be provided in the tags as well as some whitespace edits in the code itself.

No one knows for sure except the editor, but if I were you I'd just shrug it off and fill in the missing bits.

Comment: (converting "viewmodel" to `ViewModel` seem like a reasonable option - 50/50 if OP mean "view model" or "ViewModel" as in they actual question there is no space and thus not "the English phrase")

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov: I can understand that people disagree whether or not the term "view model" is one word or two words and I'm in the two-word camp, but the inline code formatting suggests either a grotesque misuse of said formatting or the editor actually thinks a `ViewModel` base class is involved. Both of which actually justify such an edit being *inappropriate*.

Answer (score 5):

From my perspective as 'not a C# programmer', I'd say that 'bit value' is plain English and not a computing term that needed highlighting.  With regard to `bool`, if you were going to refer to the generic term, you'd use 'Boolean' (complete with capital) and not `bool`; the contraction is 'obviously' a type name.  The type `string` could be marked like that, or it could be left as plain text referring to a generic string value; either makes sense.

(Here's where ignorance of C# shows…) ViewModel as a single word is probably a type name and hence could (should) be code-quoted as `ViewModel`.  However, you were referring to a generic 'view model'; it shouldn't have been capitalized or concatenated.  Now, the C# language conventions may be different and ViewModel may effectively be a term that should be used but should not be code quoted when describing view models in C#.

In C, you end up with an analogous problem with `typedef`, which is also written 'typedef' (outside code quotes).  In the C standard itself, the name is used without code quotes (footnote 10 *Thus, `int` can be replaced by a typedef name defined as `int`, …*; as an ordinary term; section 6.7.1 *The `typedef` specifier is called a "storage-class specifier" for syntactic convenience only…*).

So, I can see why the editor made or didn't make most of the changes that were made.  The 'view model' to '`ViewModel`' change is not one I would have made, but I would likely have made the same other changes had I edited the quoted material. However, I would only have edited it at all if there was some other reason to edit it in the first place (a typo, or …) — I wouldn't have edited to just add the code quotes.

There are many occasions when the code quotes *are* overused.  One that I see (and fix) is `C` as in 'the `C` programming language'.  That does not warrant code quotes.  The similar 'the [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) programming language' (embedding a tag) annoys me too and is fixed when I see it.  If you don't say 'the [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) tag on SO' or something similar, you shouldn't use the tag notation.

Comment: "you'd use 'Boolean' (complete with capital) and not `bool`" I regard this as extraordinary nitpicking. If that's your convention, no problem, but this question is talking about a much wider scope. No one is going to be confused by "Boolean" vs. "boolean" vs. "bool" (unless your question involves differences between specific data types that have specific names, e.g. a question about boxing in Java).

Comment: You’re allowed to do that.  I am an extraordinary nitpicker.  Sloppiness in phrasing gets sloppy results that may or may not be sufficiently similar to what you wanted.

Comment: I would argue it's only sloppy if it creates ambiguity, is difficult to understand, or violates well established norms, and my point is that it doesn't do any of those.